# visual studio can't create an emulator for flutter applications

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, emulation

I am currently trying to run a flutter application in visual studio.
I have successfully installed android studio with some system images.
the virtual machines are successfully created in android studio.
But unfortunately those devices couldn't be detected in visual studio
And when i tried to create a new emulator in visual studio it gives this message.

> Warning: Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86')Error: AVD not created.

so I tried to change the directory of the system image from /usr/lib/....... /google_api_playstore/x86 but it gives the same error message.
I want to note that when I use directly my phone in debugging mode. it gives this message

```
Launching lib/main.dart on PGN518 in debug mode...
ProcessException: Process "/home/osema/dev/android/myApps/lastapp/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/osema/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.2-all/9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip.lck (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:49)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: /home/osema/dev/android/myApps/lastapp/android/gradlew -v
Exited (sigterm)
```

the output of `flutter doctor -v`

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
>       • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /home/osema/dev/android/flutter
>       • Framework revision 5391447fae (2 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
>       • Engine revision 7375a0f414
>       • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at /usr/lib/android-sdk/
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
>       • ANDROID_HOME = /usr/lib/android-sdk
>       • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
>       • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
>       • Dart plugin version 181.5656
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
>       • VS Code at /usr/share/code
>       • Flutter extension version 2.22.3
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
>       • PGN518 • SG8HYDG6G66DRSPR • android-arm • Android 5.1 (API 22)

Comment: please add the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer added.

Comment: At first I'd try Flutter `dev` channel. `flutter channel dev` `flutter upgrade` `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

Open C:\Users\YourUserName.android\avd\ and delete flutter_emulator.avd folder completely

Then go VS Code -> Devices -> Create New Android Device